# Open datepicker manually angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm unable to open a date picker in angular. The goal is the get a date range, so when I change the dateStart, the second calendar should open automatically but it doesn't.

What Am I missing ?

**FIXED**

Seems to be a problem with the open-on-focus directive

Working jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/9dfLawtz/

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', function MyCtrl ($scope,$timeout) {

$scope.dateFormat = '';
$scope.dateEnd = '';
$scope.dateStart = '';

$scope.changeDateStart = function(){
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#dateEnd' ) );
  myEl.focus();
  $scope.test = true;
  myEl.parent().find("input").focus();
}

}]);
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<h2>Focus on each input and press 'enter' to see its name</h2>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="openDatePicker()">
Click 
</button>
 <md-datepicker id="dateStart" 
        ng-model="dateStart" ng-change="changeDateStart()">
    </md-datepicker>
            <md-datepicker id="dateEnd" 
        ng-model="dateEnd" md-placeholder="dateEnd" md-open-on-focus>
    </md-datepicker>
    <p>input : {{ dateFormat }}</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hx5g5g95/

Comment: Your fiddle seems ok. I don't see any problem. Tested in safari and chrome

Comment: The second calendar is not opened when change date into the first calendar, tested on chrome 55, safari, firefox

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1- Your id selector used in your timeout is not defined in your element. So you need to add id="dateEnd" to the element for this like to work:

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#dateEnd' ) );
```

2- you are setting a variable called `dateEndOpened` to true and expect the second one to open, while you used the same variable in `ng-focus` which is wrong since `ng-focus` expects a `function` rather than a variable.

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4650) for more info on how to deal with this, however the short version is to add

```
ng-focus="open()"
```

to your second date picker.

Comment: Wrong copy/paste, seems like open() doesn't do anything

Comment: There is an example of how to achieve that using a directive on the github issue page as well, you can follow that one if you like, however since the issue is closed that should work

Comment: Still the same, when I close the first calendar, the second calendar doesn't show up automaticaly